# How to handle Null pointer Exception in JSP at session.getattribute() , when session becomes invalid?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsp-tags

In servlet it is:
`<% session.setAttribute("customer",user1); %>`

where user1 is user object

in my jsp it is:

```
User user1 = (User)session.getAttribute("customer");
```

In html body

```
<h1> welcome.... <%= user1.getUserNm(); %> </h1>
```

Problem is:
 when I clear browsing history/session becomes invalid/ user obj becomes null,
 there is null pointer exception at above line
 I tried:

```
<%
    if(session.getAttribute("customer")==null){
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?msg=You are not logged in..!");
    }
 %>
```

I tried redirection to the login page, but it's not happening except that it is giving same error.
Even I tried comparing user.getusrnm() to null, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't. Write all this logic in a controller method and use the JSP solely for formatting data objects.

Comment: didnt get you. pls explain clearly

Comment: Check the null before showing username

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt work ...  https://stackoverflow.com/users/7403180/sforsujit...

Comment: use rd.include(request, response); after response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?msg=You are not logged in..!"); where rd is requestDispatcher

Answer (score 2):

You can use `httpRequest.getSession(false)` which returns `null` if session is invalid and active `httpSession` object if we have a valid session.

Then you can check if session object returned is not `null`, you should be able to get user object from session object without any null pointer.

Comment: whatever i'm checking at top of the page, control is going to that point <h1> welcome.... <%= user1.getUserNm(); %> </h1> and showing null pointer exception at this. do i need to handle exception at this point?

Comment: Nope add a scriptlet before you use any session data check for a valid session. if there isn't any active session do the redirect stuff